# How to identify alpacajs field element is changed or modified?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alpacajs

I am new to alpacajs. I have alpacajs form and also have save button for alpacajs from. More than that i have previous and next button. I currently plan to develop something like below.

For example if someone come to the alpacajs form page and if they modified some fields in form then without save they can't allow to go previous/ next so i want to disable those button. If they save the form after the modification then they can go previous/ next so i want to enable those button.

How to do this with jquery and in alpacajs?

Comment: are you using the wizard component for that or not? can you tell me more about next/prev buttons? are you using them to move to another page or another part of the form? see http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/api/wizards.html

Comment: i am not using any alpacajs wizard. Just to move another page and previous page that's it.

Comment: so it's like saving a draft form, without submit? then after saving the form you can move to different page and later on you can return to the form page to update some data and submit the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the form data as draft form in your alpaca form you have only to add the Save as draft button next to your submit and put some logic to it.

So alpaca will handle the click event on that button, but not for Previous / Next buttons.
These buttons stays out of alpaca config, and they handle only page navigation.

To add a new button to your alpaca form

```
"form": {
  "buttons": {
    "save": {
      "title": "Save draft",
      "click": function() {
        var value = this.getValue();
        // call backend service to save the form as draft
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "https://httpbin.org/post", // backend webservice
          data: value // form data
         })
        .done(function(data) {
          // check some backend response code or some flag
          // with some conditions activate next and previous buttons
          $("#previousBtn").prop('disabled', false);
          $("#nextBtn").prop('disabled', false);
        })
      }
    },
    "submit": {
      "click": function() {
        var value = this.getValue();
        alert(JSON.stringify(value, null, "  "));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Don't forget to call some other webservice to get the draft data for that form if there's any and initialize alpaca data config like this:

```
// data initialization - here you can call a service to get draft data for this form
data = {
   username: "test"
};

$("#form").alpaca({
   "data": data, // draft data if there's any
   "schema": {
     // alpaca schema config
   }
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/sf4ed3hk/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Please, ***working sample*** code below. In this, **Name** and **Feeback** fields are marked as `required` and. Bydefault, **Name** field is filled, **Feedback** is empty which throws error and **Submit** button is `disabled`, As you type something in **Feedback** field, **Submit** button got `enabled` and form is beig allow to submit because all `required` fields got filled. S*imilarly, you can handle your form like this.*

*Hope this helps !!*

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpaca@1.5.27/dist/alpaca/bootstrap/alpaca.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpaca@1.5.27/dist/alpaca/bootstrap/alpaca.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="form"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#form").alpaca({
        "data": {
          "name": "Diego Maradona",
          "ranking": "excellent"
        },
        "schema": {
          "title": "User Feedback",
          "description": "What do you think about Alpaca?",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string",
              "title": "Name",
              "required": true
            },
            "feedback": {
              "type": "string",
              "title": "Feedback",
              "required": true
            }
          }
        },
        "options": {
          "form": {
            "attributes": {
              "action": "http://httpbin.org/post",
              "method": "post"
            },
            "buttons": {
              "submit": {}
            }
          },
          "fields": {
            "name": {
              "size": 20,
              "helper": "Please enter your name."
            },
            "feedback": {
              "type": "textarea",
              "name": "your_feedback",
              "rows": 5,
              "cols": 40,
              "helper": "Please enter your feedback."
            }
          }
        },
        "view": "bootstrap-edit"
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i expect something different. Can you please check my question again and i think you will get better idea.

Comment: i didn't develop. I have idea. I want to develop. But i don't know how to develop because i am new to alpacajs. Thanks